# Foreach loop in PowerShell issue

Tags: powershell, csv, foreach

Someone please help me with my script. I have an existing csv file that just has one column and two rows under it as followed:

| Yesterday |
| --- |
| 77 |
| 22 |

I want to just add a new column for todays date with the values as per the variables i set. The outcome should look like:

| Yesterday | 01-03-2024 |
| --- | --- |
| 77 | 100 |
| 22 | 200 |

But instead, I get:

| Yesterday | 01-03-2024 |
| --- | --- |
| 77 | 100 |
| 22 | 100 |

I am a bit new to powershell still and unsure how to open an array to add $newvalue1 to just the first row and $newvalue2 to just the second row.

```
# Set the path to the existing CSV file
$csvPath = "C:\path\to\existing\file.csv"

# Import the CSV file
$data = Import-Csv -Path $csvPath

# Get today's date in the desired format for the new column name
$newColumnName = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"

$Newvalue1 = "100"
$Newvalue2 = "200"

# Add a new column to the data with today's date as the column name
foreach ($row in $data) {
    $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $newColumnName -Value $Newvalue1
}



# Export the updated data to the CSV file
$data | Export-Csv -Path $csvPath -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Data is an array starting at index zero.  So try $data[2] | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Column1" -Value "Value1"

Comment: I'm not able to replicate the issue. Made a csv with 2 entries, both having only Column1 and Column2, then ran the script, and the new CSV came out exactly like it should. Maybe close your editor to clear any stale data and try again?

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the issue here either - can you show the content of your csv file before and after running your script? (add it to your original question rather than post as a comment)

Comment: @jdweng where exactly should I put this in the script? Instead of newrow1? in the for each its still finding that second row and adding the value "newvalue"

Comment: @TheMadTechnician happens on multiple machines for me. interesting.. what about if you have an existing csv with an existing column and two rows for that existing column?

Comment: @mclayton its just a regular existing column with two rows below it. I dont see where I can add the csv file here

Comment: you can copy paste the csv as plain text inside a code block

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon thanks for this. Odd I still cant get it to paste. But if you create a csv and add a column and two rows under it. Like:

yesterday (column name)
22
33

The issue is i want to keep those values but in the new column only add "newvalue1" in the first row and "newvalue2" in the second row. Instead, it is putting that information in the 3rd and 4th row because the foreach loop is putting "newvalue" in the first two rows

Comment: I seem unable to replicate the issue with powershell 7.4.     


On a side note: `$data = Import-Csv -Path $csvPathIN | Select-Object -Property Column1, Column2, @{n = "$newColumnName"; e = { 'NewValue' } }` should be a bit more efficent than using the ForEach loop(and I think Best Practice is you should use `$data | foreach-object {...}` for this case)

Comment: So you’re saying you’ve got something like ```column1,column2`r`nvalue1,value2`r`nvalue3,value4``` and you want to change it to ```column1,column2,column3`r`nvalue1,value2,newvalue1`r`nvalue3,value4,newvalue2```? Your code doesn’t really match that - it’s adding a literal “newvalue” to all existing data and then adding two new rows that just have “newvalue1” and “newvalue2” in “column3”. Your question will be *much* clearer if you can add the “before” and “expected” csv content as I think your code and your expected result differ significantly…

Comment: Why do you want a new row when you asked to modify an existing row?  The row already exists.  You want to modify the 3rd and 4th rows in the array $data which is $data[2] and $data[3]

Comment: We all seem to struggle with understanding what the desired result is. But if I got it right, you just need to modify the line inside the foreach loop as follow: $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $newColumnName -Value "NewValue$([array]::IndexOf($data, $row)+1)"

Comment: @sirtao sorry im a bit new to powershell. Can you make the adjustments in my script and reply with the whole script on how it should be? Sorry for the confusion I modified my original post with further clarification.

Comment: @mclayton   Sorry for the confusion I modified my original post with further clarification.

Comment: @jdweng   Sorry for the confusion I modified my original post with further clarification. I just want to add values as per the variables that i defined in the new column,.

Comment: @ZivkoK   sorry im a bit new to powershell. Can you make the adjustments in my script and reply with the whole script on how it should be? Sorry for the confusion I modified my original post with further clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the 2 variables:

```
$Newvalue1 = "100"
$Newvalue2 = "200"
```

To an array:

```
$NewValues = @(
    "100"
    "200"
)
```

Then you can append new values to your collection by indexing:

```
$data = @'
Yesterday
77
22
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$newColumnName = Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd'
$index = 0
$NewValues = @(
    '100'
    '200'
)

foreach ($row in $data) {
    $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $newColumnName -Value $Newvalues[$index++]
}

$data
```

Another alternative is to use the same logic but creating new objects instead of updating them with `Select-Object` and a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.3#select-object):

```
$data = @'
Yesterday
77
22
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

[string] $newColumnName = Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd'
$index = @{ Value = 0 }
$NewValues = @(
    '100'
    '200'
)

$data | Select-Object *, @{ N = $newColumnName; E = { $NewValues[$index.Value++] }}
```

Comment: awesome i will try this! also thank you for showing me to append the values by indexing!

Comment: @PowerShellWiz as long as the column has a different name than the previous day then yes, it should work without issues (both methods)

Comment: Your script worked exactly how i want it to! However, one thing i noticed, it added a third and fourth row for only the existing first column. The values on these rows are duplicates of the 1st and 2nd rows. any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: @PowerShellWiz I think you need to create a new question explaining the new problem and what you expect to have as a result. This answer focuses on the question being asked here.

Comment: @PowerShellWiz which of the 2 methods are you testing to reproduce this issue, with `Select-Object` or `Add-Member` ?

Comment: nvm i see what went wrong that you for your help!

Comment: @PowerShellWiz np! glad it worked

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon  I must ask: why a hashtable for the loop index?

Comment: @sirtao because you must use a reference type to update a value from the callback scriptblock

Comment: Oh, right,. I absolutely forgot about it, thanks

Comment: @sirtao np! using `[ref]` or even an array `$index = @(0)` then `$NewValues[$index[0]++]` would also work, any reference type

Comment: Thanks again both of you both of yours worked for me! Do any of you know how to use winforms in PS to display data from a CSV? I just created a new post at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77753558/in-powershell-how-can-you-generate-a-chart-using-existing-values-from-existing

Comment: Does anyone know how to do the same but for rows instead? So like keeling the same column names but new values of rows under for the 3 columns? @SantiagoSquarzon

Comment: @PowerShellWiz it is easy to do but belongs in a new question. ask it and i'll try to answer

Answer (score 1):

This should work as intended

```
# Get today's date in the desired format for the new column name
$NewColumnName = Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd'

# Import the CSV file AND add an empty "today" column
$Data = Import-Csv -Path $CsvPath | Select-Object -Property Yesterday, @{n = "$newColumnName"; e = { $null } }

# array of the values you want to add.
# you could add each by themselves but this scales better if you go beyond a few rows
$NewValues = @(
    '100'
    '200'
)

# setting up the index variable
$LoopIndex = 0

# cycle through the elements in `$data`
$Data | ForEach-Object {
    # `$_` is the name for the object of the current iteration of the loop
    $_.$NewColumnName = $NewValues[$LoopIndex++]
}

##EXPORT magic, yadda yadda
```

Comment: using th wildcard `*` will use all the columns existing in the file.    
`$Data = Import-Csv -Path $CsvPath | Select-Object -Property *, @{n = "$newColumnName"; e = { $null } }`
'

This way every day it will add a new column with the date. Note well: this is bare-bone and will throw an error if run more than one time each day.