# In PowerShell, How can you generate a chart using existing values from existing csv?

Tags: powershell, winforms, csv, foreach

I need some assistance with using my csv file and creating a chart for the last 5 columns values. Example CSV:

| 12/29/23 | 12/30/23 | 12/31/23 | 1/1/24 | 1/2/24 | 1/3/24 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 16 | 22 | 28 | 38 | 55 |
| 22 | 24 | 28 | 32 | 44 | 55 |

Im not sure how to go about this. Im thinking maybe I can use System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType and use put this in a winforms. However, I am unsure how to capture all this data.

Ideally, I want to put this in a stacked column chart comparing the two rows data for each column with the dates (column name) displaying.

The output I want is something like:

[image]

The below is script is what I came up with but i get error Method invocation failed because [System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart] does not contain a method named 'ShowDialog'.

```
# Set the path to the CSV file
$csvPath = "C:\Users\Downloads\TestReport.csv"

# Import the CSV file
$data = Import-Csv -Path $csvPath

#add the assembly forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization

# Create a new chart object
$chart = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart

# Set the chart title
$chart.Titles.Add("Chart Title")

# Set the chart type to column
$chart.Series.Add("Series1") | Out-Null
$chart.Series["Series1"].ChartType = [System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType]::Column

# Add data to the chart
foreach ($column in $data | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name) {
    foreach ($row in $data) {
        $chart.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY($column, $row.$column)
    }
}

# Display the chart
$chart.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

Comment: Thanks for jumping in for assistance on this one as well! I dont want a grid view. I want a stackedcolumn chart. I'll find an example of what it should look like

Comment: just updated my description

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. Share a code snippet as well as sample CSV *in text form* (format it as code) .

Comment: @JosefZ done. please take a look

Answer (score 2):

Your current code is missing just a few details, first the chart has to be added as a `.Control` of a `Form`. It also must have a [`ChartArea`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chartarea?view=netframework-4.8.1). Here is a working example:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms, System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization

$data = @'
12/29/23,12/30/23,12/31/23,1/1/24,1/2/24,1/3/24
11,16,22,28,38,55,1
22,24,28,32,44,55,1
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$chart = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart
$chart.Titles.Add('Chart Title')
$chart.Dock = [System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle]::Fill
$chart.Series.Add('Series1') | Out-Null
$chart.ChartAreas.Add([System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea]::new())
$chart.Series['Series1'].ChartType = 'StackedColumn'
# set to `$true` so that the values are shown in the columns
$chart.Series['Series1'].IsValueShownAsLabel = $true
# foreground color for the column values 
$chart.Series['Series1'].LabelForeColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::White

# Add data to the chart (last 5 columns)
$data[0].PSObject.Properties.Name | Select-Object -Last 5 | ForEach-Object {
    foreach ($row in $data) {
        $chart.Series['Series1'].Points.AddXY($_, $row.$_)
    }
}

# Display the chart
$form = [System.Windows.Forms.Form]::new()
$form.Size = '1280, 720'
$form.Controls.Add($chart)
$form.ShowDialog()
```

[image: example]

Comment: sweet this works. Thanks. Btw, instead of entering all that data manually in the array ($data = @'
12/29/23,12/30/23,12/31/23,1/1/24,1/2/24,1/3/24
11,16,22,28,38,55
22,24,28,32,44,55
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv) ... can we do something like a $data | select-object * to get all of the values automatically? I tried this but it only returned the values from the first row.

Comment: @PowerShellWiz actually if you're reading from a file then just do `$data = Import-Csv -Path $csvPath` and the rest should stay the same

Comment: oh wow your right awesome thanks. Also, I wanted to only show the last 5 columns (12/30 -1/3, not data from 12/29/23). I tried adding -last 5 to $data = Import-Csv -Path $csvPath -last 5 but nothing changed in my output. Any thoughts on this? Also, do you see anywhere that we can use a stacked column chart so it displays the actual value in the bar? Like in the photo chart in my description. I appreciate your help!

Comment: @PowerShellWiz see the edit. for follow up questions please ask a new question

Comment: Thank you!!! This worked! By they way, it also helps to make the csv formatted as a table so the dates are duplicated